# ndb is not accepting a monkeypatched datetime.DateTime

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, monkeypatching, pytest

When testing, I'd really like to make sure that datetime.datetime.now() returns a certain datetime instance. This is how I've implemented this in a test, using pytest's `monkeypatch`function:

```
def test_auth_token_create(monkeypatch):
    newnow = datetime.datetime.now()
    later = newnow + datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)

    class fake_dt(datetime.datetime):
        def __init__(self, year, month, day):
            super(fake_dt, self).__init__(year, month, day)

        @classmethod
        def now(cls):
            return newnow

    monkeypatch.setattr(datetime,"datetime", fake_dt)

user = users.User.new("bob","password")
token = users.AuthToken.new(user=user, expires=10)
assert token.expires == later
```

But when I run my test, I get the following error:

```
BadValueError: Expected datetime, got datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 12, 15, 31, 6, 11693)
```

This error is raised in the validation method of a DateTimeProperty called 'expires'.

Inside the `AuthToken` class, there's a classmethod called `new`, which constructs an instance in the following way:

```
expires = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=expires)
instance = cls(token=token, user=user, expires=expires)
```

In here, the only variable that matters is `expires` which is initially an integer number of seconds, which is then converted to a datetime by adding a timedelta to  the datetime.datetime.now value returned by my monkeypatch.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by however monkey patch is working.

The value is [validated](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py?r=518b9e8061f43261edb9d34458845c04e3d0ab80#1935) by checking `isinstance`:

```
def _validate(self, value):
  if not isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
    raise datastore_errors.BadValueError('Expected datetime, got %r' %
                                         (value,))
```

So if it was a true subclass, `isinstance` would work just fine, e.g.

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> class B(A): pass
>>> b = B()
>>> isinstance(b, A)
True
```

You likely don't need to use `monkeypatch` at all here. Instead you can create your own custom `datetime.datetime` subclass at the toplevel and then just use that instead of manually using `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: I'd have to inject that as a dependency in some way.. But what I find weird, is that in my `fake_dt` class, I'm explicitly declaring it to be a subclass of datetime.datetime. Then, I set datetime.datetime to be my fake_tt clase, so shouldn't that evaluate to True in isinstance?

Comment: It should, but I don't know enough about `monkeypatch` to say conclusively. I'd bet it creates its own custom kind of object.